# Tokens missing in Webform Email Settings (and thus not populated in Emails received) (after upgrading)

Tags: webform-civicrm, tokens

Running Drupal 7.69 / CiviCRM 5.25.0 / PHP 7.3
After upgrading some Modules : Webform, Views Bulk Operations, i18n, and Content Access,

Emails Tokens ([submission:completed_date:long], [submission:user], [submission:values], [submission:url]) are not populated in received mails.

And those usual tokens are not shown when browsing "available tokens" in the Webform Email Template Setting.

I have asked the question on the Drupal SackExchange, but my notation there is too low to get an answer.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: i would try replicating this as a pure Drupal webform - do not use civicrm on the form. then you will be able to confirm whether this is pure Drupal issue or not.

Comment: For sure it is. Is token module still enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to both of you (Karin and Pete) for your suggestions : I have solved the problem.

I have disabled Token and Entity Tokens Modules (and requested associated Modules)

... then reactivated :

The probem comes from the Advanced User Management Module : when it is enabled, most of the tokens cannot be browsed (among which the default proposed ones in the mail content).

I will post this answer on the Drupal StackExchange.

Comment: Not sure which module that is? We use https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views - to allow us to filter e.g. the admin/people view

Comment: I don't remember why I installed this module, so ... But thank you Karin for your suggestion, ... just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Submitter   [submission:user] def. shows for me in available tokens

Drupal core 7.72

Webform 7.x-4.21

Webform Tokens 7.x-4.0